# Meteor, MongoDB - db.collection.find() for OR condition

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In MongoDB, I have the following JSONs in a collection named "Jobs"

```
{
  "userId": "testUser1",
  "default": "true",
  "someData": "data"
},
{
  "userId": "testUser1",
  "default": "false",
  "someData": "data"
},
{
  "userId": "testUser2",
  "default": "true",
  "someData": "data"
},
{
  "userId": "testUser2",
  "default": "false",
  "someData": "data"
}
```

In Meteor, I am trying to select based on two condition
- Select documents for the given `userId` **OR** `default` is `true`

I have the following code in meteor:

```
Jobs.find({$or:[{userid:"testUser1"}, {default:"true"}]});
```

But it is selecting only two JSONs:

```
{
  "userId": "testUser1",
  "default": "true",
  "someData": "data"
},
{
  "userId": "testUser1",
  "default": "false",
  "someData": "data"
}
```

and its NOT giving the below JSON in response:

```
{
  "userId": "testUser2",
  "default": "true",
  "someData": "data"
}
```

I researched with $where but even that is not working.
How to retrieve the right document from the MongoDB?

Comment: Are you sure that you are publishing the correct set of data on the client? Because if you are publishing only documents related to user1 you won't get any result for user2's documents

Comment: Let me check that... Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, my bad I did not publish the correct set of data, after correcting the publish part and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try without $or

```js
Jobs.find({userId: "testUser2", "default": "true"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you're trying to get all three of the records you mention, right?  If so, I think your issue is that the 'true' values are strings, not bools and I'm guessing that you're searching on bool.  Try this:

> db.Jobs.find()

{"userId" : "testUser1", "default" : "true", "someData" : "data" }

{"userId" : "testUser1", "default" : "false", "someData" : "data" }

{"userId" : "testUser2", "default" : "true", "someData" : "data" }

{"userId" : "testUser2", "default" : "false", "someData" : "data" }

> db.Jobs.find({ $or: [{ userId: 'testUser1' }, { default : 'true' } ] })

{"userId" : "testUser1", "default" : "true", "someData" : "data" }

{"userId" : "testUser1", "default" : "false", "someData" : "data" }

{"userId" : "testUser2", "default" : "true", "someData" : "data" }